# Segmentation fault 11 when using Anaconda with all IDEs Jupyter Notebook, Spyder etc. Mac OSX 10.13.6

Tags: anaconda, ide, macos-high-sierra, anaconda3

I am unable to open any of the IDEs in Anaconda due to segmentation fault 11.

This is the Spyder error code:

> //anaconda3/bin/pythonw: line 3:  2780 Segmentation fault: 11  //anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"

Having tried updating using:

`conda update --all`

and

`conda upgrade anaconda`

I have tried putting anaconda in the recycling bin from applications and emptying before reinstalling. Nothing works.

As far as I understand, segmentation fault 11 is a permission issue. Please help

Comment: I have this same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76124633/  It definitely appears that there is a version of jupyter on conda that is no good on a mac.  See details in my question.  Using `pip install jupyterlab` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same segmentation fault 11.
I tried changing the update to 5.4.0 in anaconda's Jupiter notebook in the settings of the launch. It took a long while but it created a new environment and it worked at first time when I tried to launch again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need some help but I saw this as I had the same problem opening jupyter notebook from the anaconda navigator.

Im not an expert in these things so I was just trying stuff out and also updated everything, but the same problem would still occur.

For some reason jupyter notebook didn't open from the anaconda navigator but it does from the **terminal**. I just opened the terminal and wrote "jupyter notebook" jupyter opened up. Maybe you could also try this with spyder.

Answer (score 0):

I have error segmentation fault 11 in my macOS. I have reinstalled it from anaconda2 to anaconda3. the error is :

```
jupyter_mac.command: line 5: 40726 Segmentation fault: 11
$DIR/jupyter-notebook
```

Hence, I read that due to terminal was showing (base) and could not read the file properly. So my solution that helps me to solve this error is:

1. type the command below to check if auto base is activated:

   ```
   conda config --show | grep auto_activate_base
   ```

if the output is:

```
auto_activate_base: True
```

you need to deactivate the auto grep by using the command below:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
```

Once successful, you may see the (base) disappear. Next close terminal and open it back.

2. run command below:

   ```
   conda update conda
   ```

once it succeeds, you may open the file in your drive:

```
//anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command
```

it will direct you to the jupyter notebook page.

Success!