# Jupyter from Conda, Segmentation Fault on macOS (10.13.6)

Tags: conda, jupyter-lab, miniconda

I am running the following command:

```bash
conda create -n jupyterlab-ext --override-channels --strict-channel-priority -c conda-forge -c nodefaults jupyterlab=3 cookiecutter nodejs jupyter-packaging
```

The above command is part of the [Jupyter labextension tutorial](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_tutorial.html#install-nodejs-jupyterlab-etc-in-a-conda-environment) and I have run this command (followed by `jlpm` described below) *successfully every day for several days*.

However **today**, after running the above `conda create`, and then activating the environment, when I try to run the jupyter-packaging program **`jlpm`** then I get the following:

```bash
~/code$ conda activate myenv
(myenv) ~/code$ jlpm
Segmentation fault: 11
```

This is happening consistently **today** on my MacBook.  **It worked fine yesterday, *and* the day before.**  (It is also working fine even today in my WLS2 environment on my PC).

I suspect that `conda` is installing a bad version of `jupyter-packaging`, or more likely, a bad version of something that `jupyter-packaging` depends upon.  I tried rebooting my mac, same issue.

Any ideas?

---

running miniconda:

```bash
~/code$ conda --version
conda 23.1.0
```

---

#### Some additional information:

- It is not actually `jlpm` that is crashing, but `jupyter` itself.
- running `jupyter` with no args, or with no subcommand, works fine.  For example:

  ```
  jupyter <enter>
  jupyter --help <enter>
  jupyter --version <enter>  # all of these work fine.
  ```
- running `jupyter` with any **subcommand**, gives `Segmentation fault: 11`, for example:

  ```
  jupyter labextension --list <enter>
  jupyter lab <enter>
  jupyter notebook <enter>  # All of these Segmentation fault: 11
  ```
- The Seg fault is always ***while importing main for the subcommand***, for example:

  - "jupyter notebook " crashes on:

    ```
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
    ```
  - "jupyter labextension --list " crashes on:

    ```
    from jupyterlab.labextensions import main
    ```
- There definitely seems to be something wrong with the conda version of jupyterlab.  If I run the `conda create` command that I listed at the top of this question, *except I leave out* `jupyterlab=3` so that jupyterlab is *not* installed, *and then after activating the environment I use **`pip install jupyterlab` then everything works fine!
- If I had another macbook, I would test if this is an issue with all macs, or just mine.  As mentioned above, I don't have this problem on WSL2 ubuntu.
- pdb seemed to indicate that the crash was in `lib/python3.11/importlib/_bootstrap.py` but that does not mean that the problem isn't with the jupyter package (from conda) only that (as I mentioned above) the crash occurs *while importing main from the specified subcommand*.

Comment: One thing to try would be to remove (or rename) `node_modules` directory and trying to run `jlpm` again.

Comment: @krassowski - Thanks for the suggestion.  The node_modules directory is not present.  I'm starting from scratch every time.  I can't even run **`jlpm --version`**, and that's even *before* running cookiecutter.

Comment: What if you try to remove jupyterlab from the equation? What happens if you just run `node` - does it also segfault?

Comment: @krassowski ... hmm good idea.  node works fine.  But jupyter itself does not.  `jupyter notebook` or `jupyter lab` ... really `jupyter <any_subcommand>` crashes with the same `Segmentation Fault 11` ... *however* `jupyter --option` with no subcommand works fine.  For example `jupyter --help` and `jupyter --version`

Comment: Can you compare `conda list` for a new environment and an older one that worked? Maybe there has been a problematic Conda Forge package build (it happens)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something like that.  Or to delve into the Jupyter code and find exactly where it's seg faulting.  I have an good idea now how to get at this.  In the meantime I have another deadline so I will come back to this in a couple of days.  (In the meantime maybe that conda forge dependency will get fixed ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can recover a working environment with last jupyterlab version by pinning libffi to 3.3.

`micromamba create -f https://prefix.dev/envs/marcbernot/mojave/conda-lock.yml -n mojave`
or
`conda create -n testmojave python=3.9 libffi=3.3 notebook jupyterlab`.
See more details [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/jupyterlab-feedstock/issues/378#issuecomment-1572731937).